# Installing node_modules per project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean

So I'm starting a project using Angular as frontend, Express and NodeJS as back end and MongoDB as DB. ( MEAN basically). Now I'm fully going to make the the project locally in webstorm, and when it's finished I'll publish it on a cloud/VPS. I'm thinking of using a local node_modules in the project with a package.json, and just add the dependencies in the packaga.json and running npm install. That means that everything is going to be installed locally, and later on when I need to deploy I just need to install Node.js and MongoDB on the server, make the database and I'll be done?

So is this the right way of doing it or not? I've never actually deployed a personal project so I don't want to mess up now and have to start over because of bad choices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the right way of doing it.

Also, if you're using git be sure to add node_modules to your gitignore file.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders

Comment: Ok thanks, now another question, Right now on my local computer I run mongoDB obviously on it's own port, Node.js back end same, but I start the front end with webstorm which I think has it's own integrated webserver. How should I handle this on a dedicated server ? I load the index page in webstorm and it starts its own webserver to run it. Do I need apache or somehing or can I do i with node.js?